# Combining IObservable<IObservable<T>> into IList<T>

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, system.reactive

I have incoming connections exposed as:

```
IObservable<double>
```

Every time a new connection is made I notify it via:

```
IObservable<IObservable<double>> m_IncomingConnections;
```

My problem is that I'd like to build an operator that I can use to do

```
IObservable<IList<double>> m_joined = m_IncomingConnections.JoinAll();
```

So assume that at the beginning I have three incoming connections the m_joined observable will be pushing Lists with three elements.

```
|--a1----a2----------a3-------
|b1---b2----b3--b4---------b5-
|---c1----c2---c3--c4---------
```

result:

```
>[a1,b1,c1]
>[a1,b2,c1]
>[a2,b2,c1]
>[a2,b2,c2]
>[a2,b3,c2]
```

You got the idea, but if a new connections comes in I'd like the array now to become of size 4 as soon as the new connection pushes new values.

All of this is so I can now use

```
m_joined.Select(vv => vv.Average());
```

To stream the average value of all streams every time a new value is pushed in.

Any suggestion about implementing such an extension for Rx?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle problem is to convert a list of observables to an observable of list.

```
IObservable<List<T>> CombineNLatest<T>(List<IObservable<T>> list){

    return list
        .Aggregate
            ( Observable.Return(new List<T>())
            , (a, n) => Observable.CombineLatest
                ( a
                , b
                , (l, e) => l.Concat(e).ToList()));
}
```

Something like that though I have not tested it. Now you have that problem you need to
build up your List>

```
IObservable<List<IObservable<T>> 
CollectList<T>
(this IObservable<IObservable<T>> input)
{
    var initial = new List<IObservable<T>>();
    return Observable.Create(observer => {

        return input.Subscribe( o => {

            initial.Append(o);
            observer.OnNext(initial);

        }

    });
}
```

Again not tested but I hope the general idea is clear. Now Chain them together

```
IObservable<IObservable<T>> input = ...;
IObservable<IObservable<List<T>>> intermediate = input
   .CollectList()
   .Select( list => CombineNLatest(list) );

IObservable<List<T>> final = intermediate.Switch();
```